# Filter dataframes based on 2 columns of another dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'nick', 'juli', 'Tom', 'nick', 'juli','nick', 'juli','Tom'], 'subject': ['eng', 'maths', 'geo', 'maths', 'science', 'geo', 'maths', 'maths', 'geo', 'science'], 'marks':[99, 98, 95, 90, 99, 98, 97, 95, 96, 98]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

df1

```
 Name    subject    marks
0   Tom     eng     99
1   Jack    maths   98
2   nick    geo     95
3   juli    maths   90
4   Tom     science 99
5   nick    geo     98
6   juli    maths   97
7   nick    maths   95
8   juli    geo     96
9   Tom     science 98
```

another dataframe as :

```
data2 = {'Name':['Jack', 'nick', 'Tom',  'juli', 'Tom', 'nick','nick', 'juli'], 'subject': ['eng', 'maths', 'geo', 'maths', 'science', 'geo',  'maths', 'geo']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)


df2

    Name    subject
0   Jack    eng
1   nick    maths
2   Tom     geo
3   juli    maths
4   Tom     science
5   nick    geo
6   nick    maths
7   juli    geo
```

I want to filter df2 based on combination of 'Names' and 'subject' in df1. If a particular combination of 'Name' and 'subject' in df1 appears more than once and then it is matched in df2. If it matches then we get those rows from df2 as output.

Desired output:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Names':['Tom', 'juli', 'nick'], 'subject': ['science', 'maths', 'geo']})

    Name    subject 
0   nick    geo 
1   juli    maths
2   Tom     science
```

can anyone help without using 'merge' option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need filter rows with duplicated values only by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` chained without this parameter and for them first rows and then use `merge` for inner join:

```
df11 = df1[df1.duplicated(subset=['Name','subject'], keep=False) & 
           df1.duplicated(subset=['Name','subject'])]

df3 = df11.merge(df2, suffixes=('_',''))[df2.columns]
print (df3)
   Name  subject
0  nick      geo
1  juli    maths
2   Tom  science
```

Another similar idea is filter columns by `df2` in `merge`:

```
cols = df2.columns
df11 = df1.loc[df1[cols].duplicated(keep=False) & df1[cols].duplicated(), cols]
df3 = df11.merge(df2)
print (df3)
   Name  subject
0  nick      geo
1  juli    maths
2   Tom  science
```

Comment: this works for the particular case asked. I was looking for a generalized solution, for example, what to do if I have to look for the combination 'Name' and 'subject'  in df1 appearing more than twice/thrice instead of 'once'.

Comment: @sak - Then change `df1.duplicated(subset=['Name','subject'], keep=False)` to `df1.groupby(['Name','subject'])['Name'].transform('size').gt(2)` for greater like `2`